# signum function

Tags: analysis

I don't understand everything of the following sum:
$$\sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{\sigma\in S_3}sign(\sigma)v^{\sigma(2)}w^{\sigma(3)}\partial_{x^i}$$
What is the meaning of the $\sigma(2/3)$ in the exponent of v/w.
What are the $\sigma$ of $S_3$?

Could someone please help me here?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$S_n$ is the group of permutations on $n$ symbols with order $n!$. $\sigma(j)$ is the image of $j$ under the permutation $\sigma$. For example, let

$$ \sigma = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

This array (see the link below) tells us that $\sigma(1) = 2$, $\sigma(2) = 3$, and $\sigma(3) = 1$. The inner sum asks you to sum over all such permutations of $S_3$, and the signature of a permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ is

$$ \operatorname{sgn} \sigma = (-1)^k $$

where $k$ is the number of disjoint cycles (transpositions) your permutation can be constructed from. The permutation I have constructed above can be written as a sequence of transpositions - first swap $1$ and $3$, then $1$ and $2$. Now $k=2$, and $\operatorname{sgn}\sigma = 1$. We would also call this an even permutation; those with signature $-1$ would be called odd. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) for more info.

Comment: ok so a $\sigma$ is a permutation. But I still don't what the image of j under the permutation $\sigma$ $\sigma(j)$ is. Could you give me a quick example for a better understanding?

Comment: See my most recent edit. Again, I suggest reading the suggested link and any algebra text's section on permutations.